# how do I do an authentication triage in Laravel 6.12?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using **laravel 6.12** using the Authentication artisan command

`php artisan ui vue --auth`

I have been following https://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-how-to-check-more-than-just-emailpassword/ website .  I would like to know the steps needed to authenticate with a triage i.e company, email address and password.

I am receiving a duplicate when I add company name, it thinks this is the email address.  Where do you change this? And I am recieving the following error.

*BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::company does not exist.*

`$credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
 $credentials = array_add($credentials, 'company');`

I need to Verify the Company name as part of the authentication process. with email, password & Company. Does anyone know how to authenticate using three authentication credentials?

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

}
'''

Comment: show your codes what you have modified ?

Answer (score 0):

---

**Note:** The tutorial you linked shows a bad way of logging in a User using a raw SQL query!. Please use a more standard way.

---

#### To login a user using multiple properties do something like this in your Controller method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //... request validation logic

    //take only what is needed to verify login
    $credentials = request(['company', 'email', 'password']);

    //verify login
    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Invalid password'
        ], 401);
    }

    //Login user, as you're using Vue I assume you use either JWT or Passport

    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, using passport,  please notice that I have added the logincontroller.php code,  Where would you add your contribution?  I am assuming the logincontroller.php file,

can you provide more details,  and thanks for your response.

Comment: You could have a custom login route point to this login method which you can put in any controller. LoginController also It should work fine

Comment: Is there any examples of this that you can point me to?  Preferably for a three way authentication? Thanks for your support.